# If I use PhoneGap do I have to know Objective-C and will my app go into the directory?

Tags: cordova

If I use PhoneGap will I build web app as usual?  How does PhoneGap tie into the web building process?  Can I be "real app" like ones built in Objective-C (I thought that was a requirement to be in the app directory)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use PhoneGap will I build web app as usual?

Essentially. PhoneGap gives you extra things in JavaScript you can use to do things like accessing the camera that you couldn't do with regular JavaScript.

> Can I be "real app" like ones built in Objective-C (I thought that was a requirement to be in the app directory)?

No, you don't need to know Objective-C (all the Objective-C has been written for you by PhoneGap's developers) and yes, it'll go into the App Store just fine.

Comment: say I didn't use phonegap, do you still have to have things in objective-c to get into the app store?  Or is that what you are saying phonegap gives me?

Comment: You can't submit just plain HTML to the store. You need an Objective-C wrapper like PhoneGap to submit a HTML/CSS/JS app.